# How to write correct and efficient code in Ruby in Rails equal to SQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I stucked and I don't know how to write correct query in RoR to achieve active record.

Relations between tables:

```
imed_patient has one imed_operator
imed_operator has many imed_operator_contacts
imed_patient has_many imed_operator_conatc through imed_operator
```

Definition of models :

```
class ImedOperator < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = "imed_operator"
    self.primary_key = "code"

  has_one :imed_patient, foreign_key: 'r_opr_code'
  has_many :imed_operator_contact, :foreign_key => "r_opr_code"
end

class ImedOperatorContact < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = "imed_operator_contact"
end

class ImedPatient < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = "imed_patient"
    self.primary_key = "code"

    has_many :visit, :foreign_key => "r_ptn_code"
    belongs_to :imed_operator , foreign_key: 'r_opr_code'
    has_many :imed_operator_contact, through: :imed_operator
end
```

Good SQL in PostgreSQL:

```
select * from imed_patient 
      INNER JOIN imed_operator ON imed_patient.r_opr_code = imed_operator.code 
      INNER JOIN imed_operator_contact ON imed_operator.code = imed_operator_contact.r_opr_code 
    where (imed_operator_contact.r_ct_id = 1 or imed_operator_contact.r_ct_id = 2) and imed_operator_contact.value = '501'
```

Code now (not working) is:

```
@pacjenci = ImedPatient.ImedOperatorContact.where('imed_operator_contact.r_ct_id = ? or imed_operator_contact.r_ct_id = ? and imed_operator_contact.value = ?',1,2,'+48501')
```

Error during run:

> NoMethodError in PacjenciController#szukajpacjenttel undefined method
>   `ImedOperatorContact' for #

Anybody can help me ?

SOLVED

Thanks guys for inspiration. I solved it by:

```
@pacjenci = ImedPatient.joins(:imed_operator).joins(:imed_operator_contact).where('imed_operator_contact.value' => '+48501', 'imed_operator_contact.r_ct_id' => [1,2])
```

I used information from [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joins) point 12.1.3.2 Joining Nested Associations (Multiple Level)

Special Thanks to [Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1266795/andyv)

Comment: Maybe this is helpful for you. If the complexity of my SQl statement grows i prefer to invoke SQL directly. `http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Querying.html` so something like `ImedPatient.find_by_sql()` in your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your ImedPatient:

```
has_many :imed_operator_contacts, through: :imed_operator
```

With that you should be able to use any ActiveRecord/arel style query:

```
imed_patient.imed_operator_contacts.where(value: '501')
```

Comment: This is not Arel, btw. This is ActiveRecord. Arel code is much less pretty :) ([`users.where(users[:age].eq(10)).project(Arel.sql('*'))`](https://github.com/rails/arel))

Comment: Yes, I'm quite aware.

Comment: yet you say "arel style". this is not quite arel style, is it?

Comment: I suggested that you could use any ActiveRecord/arel style and gave an example of one such type of query.  The pedantic nitpicking is annoying.  Please stop.  I've seen you do it in several other places and it sets you apart as a "know it all" who does not work well with others.

Comment: I added through connection and "arel" style. I updated question and error result.

Comment: The form of the query is incorrect.  The "has_many :widgets, through: :maker" makes available a method with the same name as the argument to the call -- in this case widgets -- NOT the name of the joined class.

Comment: With ^ that in mind try this: imed_patient.imed_operator_contacts.where(value: '+48501', r_ct_id: [1,2])